# How do I style the elements of the same div with a different widths

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am currently creating a task list project in react js and decided to start styling it a bit with css. My problem is that whenever I input a new task on my task list I want to create a box around it with some colors. I decided to use the css's `width:125%` property. However, I learnt that while it works perfectly for the first task, whenever a new task was added with a longer content, it changes the whole width for everything with the #task id which is all the previous tasks. How do I prevent this. Here is some of my code.

My React Code:

```
<ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", float: "left" }}>
        {this.props.thing.map((test) => (
          <div id="task" style={{ width: "125%" }}>
            <p>{test}</p>
            <button>X</button>
            <br />
          </div> 
        ))}
      </ul>
```

My css:

```
#task {
  height: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #ed7014;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #fa8128;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#task p {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
#task button {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: You have styling being applied via a CSS file and also inline in the markup. Stick to the former.

Comment: By setting the width of one div in that same "column" the others will follow. That's the expected behavior based on your current markup + styling.

Comment: Also, you have invalid markup there. You should have `li` elements as children of your `ul`, not `div`.

Comment: `id` should be unique. Your loop is creating possible multiple elements with the same `id`

Comment: To pile on a bit, don't use line breaks for spacing. Use margins in your CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try moving all the styling in the .css file.

Example:

```
#task p {
    width: 125px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Please try using css overflow: property for your #task.

This link will help you decide what u want to do.. click here --> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Comment: @Bop, Did it solve ur problem. Plz let me know if my answer solved ur problem.